# ios mdm push notification not received only on few ios devices

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

We have successfully developed an ios MDM solution. The problem we face now is, the MDM push notifications(the wake up call step) is not receiving on a few iOS devices, but works very well for other iOS devices.

I had already searched for this issue on the forums. Most of them said that if the device is behind Wifi, or any other restricted network which block the apple ports, then the push will not be received. But these devices are not receiving the notification even from 3g network. Is there any thing that need to be enabled / disabled in the device for it to receive the push notification ie. the wake up call from the Apple server?

Comment: Show us the relevant code, and the steps you've taken so far to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Actually there is no issue with the code. The code is working fine, as the Push notifications are received successfully for 90% of the devices. But for the rest 10% of the devices, the wake up call is not received. We have this issue of not receiving the notification wen we are behind a corporate Wifi.. But in 3g, it should ideally work. But even in 3g it is not working only on a few devices.. Since the device in which it is not working is not in our hands, we are not able to see the logs on the device also.. is there any restriction for Jail broken devices?

Comment: Then you'll probably need to change the device, the device settings, or the code, or your firewall settings or....  But without more information, your question is pretty much a [Hail Mary pass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail_Mary_pass).

Comment: Take a look at these:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728984/apple-mdm-push-error-but-only-to-some-ios-devices

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141290/why-would-only-some-devices-be-receiving-push-notifications

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832667/push-notification-is-successfully-sent-but-the-device-does-not-receive-occasio